# Setting and updating custom views for AlertDialogs

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-alertdialog

All the Dialogs in my app are constructed with AlertDialog except for my Bluetooth-picker dialog. My goal is to create an AlertDialog for that as well.

***Problem:***

If I want to add a spinning progress bar to the top right I'd need to use the .setCustomTitle(view) method of AlertDialog's Builder. This works, but I'd like to use the default AlertDialog title style for this title as well, but I'm unsure how to do that.

So basically I want the blue text of the second screenshot to appear exactly like the black one in the first one. I'd prefer to do this dynamically instead of just finding out the exact values AlertDialog uses and hard code those.

**My attempts:**

I looked through the AlertDialog's source and found that "The actual style that an AlertDialog uses is a private implementation". However I also found out that they use R.attr.alertDialogTheme as attribute and [I can get the resourceId of the theme](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5b85084adddd915da2cf738925e4eb6c)

I tried creating a TextView with that resourceId but that didn't work (TextView apeared like it would unstyled).

Default AlertDialog title style:

[image: Default AlertDialog title style]

My current title:

[image: My current title]

You can recreate the Dialogs shown above with the following code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/34edc1afbdb7e9d10d9adbda63d4cd8c

The xml's required are: [content.xml](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e49e69615fc57a5ca65b31b59b6abc1e) and [title.xml](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ebfda25d8bf412ceb410ef07d263e14) (and [colors.xml](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e3540adacd81c40ea54972de343f8be) and [styles.xml](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8268fa6e8ba1824872c2659ab09a92b3) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have defined the **textColor** `android:textColor="#33B5E5"` of your **textView** in your **`title.xml`**. **Just change it to the color you want.**

Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="9dp"
    android:paddingBottom="18dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/customTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Custom title view"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/anotherText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customTitle"
    android:paddingTop="9dp"
    android:text="Another TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

### To update the view dynamically:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View yourTitleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title, null);
        TextView yourTitle = (TextView) yourTitleView.findViewById(R.id.customTitle);
        yourTitle.setText("Your new title text");//Dynamical text
        yourTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa000")); //Dynamical color

        //Your AlertDialog
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setCustomTitle(yourTitleView) //The title's TextView's style should be the
                // same as the the one of the dialog normal AlertDialog's Title Style (see example above)
                .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null))
                .setPositiveButton("Start", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

Don't forget to define good ID's to your views.

### For another misunderstandings

**To format text wihtout custom dialogs just use an Html function**

```
Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'> Your black text </font>")
```

Example:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
         .setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'> Your black title </font>"))
         .setView(yourView)
         .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      //Stuff to do
                   }
              })
         .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      //Stuff to do
                      dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               })
         .show();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you missed the point, I want to add a spinning progress bar to the top right of the title. This should be done with 'AlertDialog.Builder(this).setCustomTitle(view)' , however then I need to use a TextView in a layout for my text instaid of using the default .setTitle(). So the goal is to set the text color & size of the TextView to exactly the values that the AlertDialog uses, preferably dynamicly (as the exact color/size is subject to change and is not under my controll). If getting the exact AlertDialog Style is not possible I'd like to get as close as possible.

Comment: And the first screenshot is how I want the text to look which is just the normal .setTitle("my text here"), without the html.

Comment: Ok I got it, I saw you updated your question, please provide the xmls of your views (layouts), and styles and colors (values). And the code that you are using to inflate them.

Comment: I updated my answer, it was not anything I expected.

Comment: That indeed solves my problem thanks! I didn't notice it took the color from there, I thought the blue color of the dialog was hidden in the AlertDialog's Style

Comment: Good, anyway I'll update some basic code to update the view dynamically

Comment: Buddy, change the title to your question so other people can refer correctly to these types of problems. Something like "Setting and updating custom views for AlertDialogs" would be great.